# Extjs: How to get the record from a form

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I get the record from a form in Extjs? When I use form.getRecord() it returns undefined. Here is the form content

```
var form = me.getPropertyForm().getForm();
console.log(form);
form.getRecord() = ====> undefined
```

[image]

Comment: use form.getValues()

Comment: or use can directly use form._record

Comment: Did you load the record using `form.loadrecord()`? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getRecord

Comment: Try `console.log(form._record)`. If undefined, it means the record seen on the screenshot gets in thereafter.

Comment: _record worked. thanks

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `_record`. You are hacking to get the values, but don't know why `getRecord()` is not working. Hacking like this will get you in trouble. Ask yourself why `._record` is filled, but `getRecord()` (which returns _record, nothing else) is undefined.. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Basic.html#Ext-form-Basic-method-getRecord